# main/binary-i386/Package(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

So i ran the sudo apt-get update command as usual and I got this error, I have already tried the answers posted on this site and other an nothing works. Can anyone help me solve this? This i what the console shows.

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Reddit posting](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/48oje6/linux_how_to_fix_failed_to_fetch/)
it seems that even if you have an amd64 system, the APT frontends still look for i386 descriptions in the file which is fetched for that source.  And since Google have dropped support for i386, they have stopped describing it.  The solution is apparently restricting interpretation of the fetched file to only arch=amd64 in the sources.list file.

`deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

Comment: I don't if it really works, but the error disappeared.

Comment: Thanks alot! never came by that page before but it solved the problem =)

Comment: @logoff , if you installed the google-chome-stable update, it may have fixed up the file.  Also, the package installs a file in /etc/cron.daily whose purpose is to update the flle in sources.list.d.  If you read the comments in that shell script, it was initially created to deal with distupgrades that somehow mangled the file, so it needed to be corrected.  So if you never tried an update until cron.daily ran, when it did run, there may have been a correction applied to the file.

Comment: the Reddit post has added valuable information and the Web UPD8 Team has created an official answer: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html

Comment: The WebUpd8 team has noted version 49.0.2623.87 fixed this, so any workarounds (such as setting the filesystem immutable bit for the APT list file) should probably be undone.